# How to simulate Google Form's 'Send' button in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

When sending a Google Form manually via the "Send" button within a form, you would see that the email addresses are recorded in the "Responses" tab, even if they have not responded yet, and listed under the "Waiting for x response(s)" section (as shown in the screenshot).

How to achieve the same using Google Apps Script?

I can dispatch a Gmail email via script like (the code) below, but this does not track/list the emails where the form was sent to.

```
GmailApp.sendEmail('some1@company.xyz',form.getTitle(),form.getPublishedUrl());
```

[image]